# To change password in mysql

Tags: php, codeigniter

In the below  codeigniter code i have placed controller and model i can login by entering username and password.Now i have to implement is to change password.Pls anyone help me to solve the issue.

Controller:

```
<?php

class Login extends CI_Controller {

    function index()
    {
        $data['main_content'] = 'login_form';
        $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);      
    }

    function validate_credentials()
    {       
        $this->load->model('membership_model');
        $query = $this->membership_model->validate();

        if($query) // if the user's credentials validated...
        {
            $data = array(
                'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                'is_logged_in' => true
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            redirect('site1/members_area');
        }
        else // incorrect username or password
        {
            $this->index();
        }
    }   

    function signup()
    {
        $data['main_content'] = 'signup_form';
        $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
    }


    function create_member()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        // field name, error message, validation rules
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'Name', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', 'Last Name', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email_address', 'Email Address', 'trim|required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|min_length[4]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|max_length[32]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password2', 'Password Confirmation', 'trim|required|matches[password]');
         $this->load->helper('date');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('signup_form');
        }

        else
        {           
            $this->load->model('membership_model');

            if($query = $this->membership_model->create_member())
            {
                $data['main_content'] = 'signup_successful';
                $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
            }
            else
            {
                $this->load->view('signup_form');           
            }
        }

    }

    function logout()
    {
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        $this->index();
    }

}
?>
```

model:

```
<?php

class Membership_model extends CI_Model {

    function validate()
    {
        $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
        $this->db->where('password', md5($this->input->post('password')));
        $query = $this->db->get('membership');

        if($query->num_rows == 1)
        {
            return true;
        }

    }

    function create_member()
    {

        $new_member_insert_data = array(
            'first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
            'last_name' => $this->input->post('last_name'),
            'email_address' => $this->input->post('email_address'),         
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', now()),
            'password' => md5($this->input->post('password'))                       
        );

        $insert = $this->db->insert('membership', $new_member_insert_data);
        if ($this->db->_error_number() == 1062)
                {
                echo"<script>alert('This value already exists');</script>";
                }
                if ($this->db->_error_number() == "")
                {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('create', 'create');
                }

        return $insert;
    }


    function curdate() {
    // gets current timestamp
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila'); // What timezone you want to be the default value for your current date.
    return date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
}
```

Comment: Do you actually have a specific issue, or do you just want someone to write your code for you?

Comment: Just update the password where username= username of the person? This is just pure laziness

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these simple steps:

1. Create a view with the change password form (i.e. email, current password and new password)
2. Create in your controller a function that retrieve the data from the form and check if exists user with that email and that password
3. Create a function in your model to make the update with `$this->db->update()`
4. From your controller run the model function